# ModelState.IsValid always true when testing Controller in Asp.Net MVC Web Api

Tags: c#, testing, asp.net-web-api, modelstate

I have tried to make this work and made many google/stackoverflow searches with no luck at all.

I have a simple Model:

```
public class MovieModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A method in the controller:

```
// POST: api/Movies
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]MovieModel movieModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

And a test method (is an integration test, but the same would happen in unit tests):

```
[TestMethod]
public void MoviesController_Post_Without_Name()
{
    // Arrange
    var model = new MovieModel();
    model.Name = "";

    // Act
    var result = controller.Post(model);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(InvalidModelStateResult));
    Assert.AreEqual(6, controller.Get().Count());
}
```

Despite the fact that the model is clearly invalid it always evaluates the IsValid property to true.

I tried many approaches so far without success.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution probably works, but a better way is using [ApiController.Validate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.validate(v=vs.118).aspx) method.

```
public void MoviesController_Post_Without_Name()
{
    // Arrange
    var model = new MovieModel();
    model.Name = "";

    // Act
    controller.Validate(model);   //<---- use the built-in method
    var result = controller.Post(model);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(InvalidModelStateResult));
    Assert.AreEqual(6, controller.Get().Count());
}
```

Comment: I tried this .Validate method before, but it doesn't exist. I'm using MVC 5.

Comment: The microsoft reference shows the Validate method, for version 5 of MVC , but it simply don't work, neither Intellisense nor build works.

Comment: @AndréBaptista Why are you talking about MVC? `ApiController` is a Web API class, and is found in `System.Web.Http`. Ensure you added the correct NuGet packages to the test project.

Comment: Yes, I know it sounds weird, but I checked out everything:
- The nuget package (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core) is installed and is 5.0.0 version, both in Web and Test projects;
- The dll System.Web.Http is referenced and is 5.0.0 version on both the web project and the test project;
- the using directive is there;
- my controller inherits from ApiController;

When I click "Go to definition" (F12 key) over ApiController it shows the method list, and there isn't neither Validate nor TryValidate methods.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/80n/archive/2012/03/13/unittesting-controller-dataannotation-validation-in-mvc3--modelstate.isvalid-always-true.aspx) site, I found out the solution:

```
private void SimulateValidation(object model)
{
    // mimic the behaviour of the model binder which is responsible for Validating the Model
    var validationContext = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext, validationResults, true);
    foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
    {
        this.controller.ModelState.AddModelError(validationResult.MemberNames.First(), validationResult.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

And including one line in the test method like this:

```
public void MoviesController_Post_Without_Name()
{
    // Arrange
    var model = new MovieModel();
    model.Name = "";

    // Act
    SimulateValidation(model);
    var result = controller.Post(model);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(InvalidModelStateResult));
    Assert.AreEqual(6, controller.Get().Count());
}
```

Hope that helps someone, it would have saved me some hours hunting the web.

Comment: Worked for Core 2.0, for nested just do `SimulateValidation(model); SimulateValidation(model.child);`

Comment: Thank you so much @Andre Baptista, this works for me

Answer (score 1):

On WebAPI 5.2.7:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MoviesController_Post_Without_Name()()
{
    // Arrange
    var model = new MovieModel();
    model.Name = "";

    controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
    controller.Validate(model);

    // Act
    var result = controller.Post(model);

    // Assert
    ...
```

This article helped me: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
public MyResultData Post([FromBody] MyQueryData queryData)
{
    if (!this.Request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpConfiguration")) 
    {
        this.Request.Properties["MS_HttpConfiguration"] = new HttpConfiguration();
    }

    this.Validate(queryData);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Also check out this question:
[Validate fails in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753206/validate-fails-in-unit-tests)

Answer (score 0):

Manually add a model error:

```
// Arrange
controller.ModelState.AddModelError("fakeError", "fakeMessage");

// Act
var result = controller.Post(model);
```